# Buenas Como puedo hacer un Formulario en python?

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *

raiz=tk()

raiz.mainloop()
```

En `raiz=tk` me marca error. No sé porqué y si me pudieran decir si hay formas más sencillas de hacer un formulario

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que error? usa el boton [edit] y agrega como texto el error que aparece

Comment: La manera correcta: `raiz = Tk()`

Answer (score 0):

el error debe estar en "tk" ya que la letra "t" va en mayúsculas.
si por hacer formularios de forma más simple te referís a arrastar y soltar pódes hacerlos con qtcreator junto a pyqt5, pero tkinter es lo más fácil de aprender en la curva, pyqt es más profesional al final, pero requiere mayor tiempo de aprendizaje para todo, si es para cosas simples cualquiera de los dos, hay más entornos pero no los uso.
otra cosa, seguramente estás copiando el código de algún lado, prestá más atención a los detalles, python es sensible a la diferencia de mayúsculas y minúsculas.